# Flask-SocketIO - How to emit an event from a sub-process

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a Flask app which upon certain rest call is running several modules using a ProcessPoolExecutor.

**UPDATED:** Added redis as a message queue (using docker, redis as redis's host)

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://redis')

(...)

def emit_event(evt, message):
    socketio.emit(evt, message, namespace='/test')

@app.route('/info', methods=['GET'])
def info():
    emit_event('update_reports', '')

(...)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

Now that I added redis, it still works when emitting from the main app.
Here some from the code I'm running the sub-process:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    self.socketio = SocketIO(async_mode='eventlet', message_queue='redis://redis')

    (...)
    future = self.executor.submit(process, params)
    future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(self.finished_callback, pid))
```

Then in that callback I'm calling the `emit_event` method:

```
def finished_callback(self, pid, future):
    pid.status = Status.DONE.value
    pid.finished_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow
    pid.save()

    self.socketio.emit('update_reports', 'done', namespace='/test')
```

Getting and sending/ emitting messages from/to the client from my controller works just fine, also if I call /info from curl or postman my client gets the message -but- when trying to emit an event same way from within this subprocess callback, now it shows this error:

This is mostly for notifications, like notifying when a long process has finished and stuff like that.

`INFO:socketio:emitting event "update_reports" to all [/test]
ERROR:socketio:Cannot publish to redis... retrying
ERROR:socketio:Cannot publish to redis... giving up`

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to emit from your sub-process? Also you mentioned a `/info` route, but your example has `/test`. I assume that is the route that you are invoking from curl?

Comment: thanks for your reply Miguel, in the subprocess I'm just importing the `emit_event` method from the main py file it lives in and using it same way as I use it in that `/test` call.  Yes, that's the url i'm invoking. And the result is that from the sub-process the event/ message never arrives (and there is no error in console)

Comment: @Miguel I've just added some more code, let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific rules that you need to follow in setting up the Flask-SocketIO extension so that external processes can emit, which include the use of a message queue that the main and external processes use to coordinate efforts. See the [Emitting from an External Process](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process) section of the documentation for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just tried by running what's written there from my sub-process, however this is what I get in the logs `Cannot publish to redis... retrying, giving up`

Comment: I've just updated the question with more details and code.

Comment: Well, it seems your sub-processes are not connecting to Redis. Can you try writing a simple script that connects to the message queue and emits? If that works, then you have to figure out what in your child process is affecting the connection to redis.

Comment: Right, and I've fixed it right away. Also added the eventlet.monkey_patch() thing there at the top.  And now, the event arrives from the main thread but from the subprocess I get another error:

`AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'`, (and of course the message also don't arrive because it exploits before) any ideas?

Comment: The sub-processes do not need to use eventlet, only the main process does. It seems something that you are doing in your subprocesses is not compatible with eventlet, so better not use it there. You can force Socket.IO to not use eventlet by passing `async_mode='threading'` in the `SocketIO` class constructor and removing all the monkey patching.

Comment: I did that, and took out the monkey_patch thing from the subprocess class, with no success.
However I tried to take out the monkey_patching and redis thing from the main process also, and the subprocess worked again.

--Actually-- the subprocess worked, the problem was that it was breaking here `future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(self.finished_callback, pid))`' same error and callback not being called.

Comment: Btw this subprocess is being called from another class which is used in the same flask app, maybe that influences somehow? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Somehow looks like the ProcessPoolExecutor doesn't like this monkey patching even though I did the monkey_patch in the main class; looks it does actually affects everything?

Comment: Can you start your child process(es) separately then? I haven't really worked with the executor myself, I prefer to keep things separate and start each service on its own. If you are looking for alternatives that I have seen used successfully, Celery and RedisQueue are both good, but I insist that you make sure these worker processes do not use eventlet, since it seems you are using a function that eventlet does not support.

Comment: I'll check celery then, btw I've just tried replacing the ProcessPoolExecutor by a ThreadPoolExecutor one, and it doesn't exploit, and as per the logs it "emits" the event, but the client never gets it  `INFO:socketio:emitting event "update_reports" to all [/test]`

Comment: I've tried by running a separated script and it works.
I also see now that using the ThreadExecutorPool works also (not with the Process one).  I might consider mooving to Celery.
Thank you so much for your help!